# Ultra Light YouTube Player

Tags: html, css, sass

I am currently building an "ultra light" youtube player focusing on fast page load and minimum resourses needed.

The idea is to have an empty iframe and load the youtube embed url only with the link targeting the iframe.

This way, the youtube content and/or scripts are not loaded on page load but only after the user decides to see that content.

I used a low resolution youtube video poster as background-image and customized the link to look and feel like a play button.

My main obstacle right now is how to hide the play button once it is clicked.

I was able to emulate the hide effect with ":focus" selector in CSS, but it is not the preferable way because if you click elsewhere or even on the hidden button, either the button shows up or the iframe reloads.

I know I could be doing this jquery or javascript way but I am really trying to run all my apps on pure html+css

Anyone can help?
Best regards and thanks in advance

codepen: http://codepen.io/s3m3nT3s/pen/NdwEMx

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#video {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 700px;
  position: relative;
  background: url(http://img.youtube.com/vi/dQw4w9WgXcQ/mqdefault.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#video::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
}

#video a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
  width: 68px;
  height: 48px;
  background-color: #1f1f1f;
  opacity: 0.8;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 48px;
  border-radius: 17px/13px;
}
#video a:hover {
  background-color: #cd201f;
  opacity: 1;
}
#video a:focus {
  opacity: 0;
}

iframe {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="video">
  <iframe name="youtube-video"></iframe>
  <a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;autoplay=1" target="youtube-video" rel="nofollow">&#9654;</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already got my code to work...

Made it with data uri as in example:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#video {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 700px;
  position: relative;
  background: url(http://img.youtube.com/vi/c73BsSHOCwQ/mqdefault.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#video:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
}

#video:after {
  content: "▶";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
  width: 68px;
  height: 48px;
  background-color: #1f1f1f;
  opacity: 0.8;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 48px;
  border-radius: 17px/13px;
  z-index: 1;
}

#video:hover:after {
  background-color: #cd201f;
  opacity: 1;
}

iframe {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  border: none;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<div id="video">
 <iframe src="data:text/html;charset=utf-8,%3Ca%20style%3D%22display%3Ainline-block%3Bwidth%3A100%25%3Bheight%3A100%25%22%20href%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fembed%2Fc73BsSHOCwQ%3Frel%3D0%26showinfo%3D0%26autoplay%3D1%22%20rel%3D%22nofollow%22%3E%3C%2Fa%3E" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Regards

Comment: +1 clever :–). Should you manage to solve the annoying "missing-autoplay" on iOS – please leave a comment.

Comment: @Jacob For now, I just run a php routine over the user agent of the client and if it detects mobile, instead of serving this code, it injects the "normal" youtube Iframe without autoplay function. It does not serve my purpose on  "ultra light" player, but it sure is more user interaction thinking.